# Is the essential numerical range of an operator T non empty?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

How can it be proven that the essential numerical range of an operator T is non empty?

Answer (score 5):

I assume $T$ is a bounded operator on a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.

$\lambda\in \mathbb C$ belongs to the essential numerical range $W_e(T)$ of $T$ iff there exists an orthonormal sequence $\{e_n\}$ such that
$$
\langle Te_n, e_n \rangle \to \lambda 
$$

Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal base of $\mathcal H$. The sequence
$$
\langle Te_n, e_n \rangle
$$ 
is bounded by $\lVert T \rVert$ and so you can extract a convergent subsequence from it. Its limit belongs to $W_e(T)$.

Answer (score 0):

The essential numerical range contains the essential spectrum and the later is never empty.

Comment: Does this assume something about the linear operator $T$?  Note the assumptions stated in the other Answer.